# How do I find the technical name for a function so I can assign a hotkey to it?

Tags: customization

I'd like to assign hotkeys to certain actions, like for example "Extrude Individual Faces"? Is there a list of all possible commands somewhere?

For example, in this picture "view3d.edit_mesh_extrude_move_normal" is the command or function. So where can I find a list of all possible commands so I can assign hotkeys to them?

[image]

Comment: Yes, that list does help but turning on the python tooltips also worked, so should the question be left so Robert can get the rep credit?

Comment: @ThomBlairIII The question (and it's answers) will still be here if it's closed as a duplicate.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can turn on *Python Tooltips* in *User Preferences >
Interface > Display*. Hover over the tool or button you
want to assign a shortcut for and the function (operator) name appears.

[image: Tooltip - Operator]

Then press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>C</kbd> to copy that operator call and paste it into blenders python console <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>V</kbd>. Remove the brackets, type `.idname_py()` and press <kbd>Enter</kbd> to get the **python identifier** of the operator, which can be used to create or edit shortcuts in *User Preferences > Input*.

[image: Console - Operator Id]

Example: `bpy.ops.object.origin_set(type='ORIGIN_CURSOR')` 
Python identifier: `object.origin_set`

Comment: I did not know tooltips could be turned off.  I use them all the time to help me learn the python property names for fields.

Answer (score 4):

Many buttons will have an option to create (or if a shortcut already exists, remove or change) a shortcut when you right click on the relevant button:

[image]

Answer (score 2):

You can use the output in the info window to get the python equivalent command of an action. The info panel will echo all commands.

[image]

Comment: I can't remember which, but I think there are some commands which this doesn't show.

Comment: @RayMairlot possible, I don't know.