# Find active camera from Python

Tags: python, camera

I could just use:

```
obj_camera = bpy.data.objects["Camera"]
```

to get the camera, but it is possible to have a scene with multiple cameras.

So if that is the case, how can I choose the active one?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The property you are looking for is 'Scene.camera'.

If you have '[python tooltips](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/7878/how-do-i-find-the-technical-name-for-a-function-so-i-can-assign-a-hotkey-to-it/7879#7879)' enabled in the user preferences you can hover over the camera field in the 'Scene' tab of the 'Properties' area, to reveal the python code for this property:

[image]

The code to access this property for the current scene and assign it to a variable is:

```
obj_camera = bpy.context.scene.camera
```

Answer (score 9):

"active" is a weak definition, there is the scene camera (can also be `None`), but it could also mean the active object and that object being a camera. A special case is operator *Set active object as camera*, which makes an arbitrary object the scene camera.

```
cam_ob = bpy.context.scene.camera

if cam_ob is None:
    print("no scene camera")
elif cam_ob.type == 'CAMERA':
    print("regular scene cam")
else:
    print("%s object as camera" % cam_ob.type)

ob = bpy.context.object
if ob is not None and ob.type == 'CAMERA':
    print("Active camera object")
```

Answer (score -1):

I use the following code:

```
cameras_obj = [cam for cam in bpy.data.objects if cam.type == 'CAMERA']
for cam in cameras_obj:
    if cam.hide_render:
        print("la camara {} esta desactivada".format(cam.name))
    else:
        print("la camara {} esta activada".format(cam.name))
```

Comment: Suggest iterate through all objects of the scene `bpy.context.scene.objects` instead.

Comment: I was under the impression `hide_render` was an object property that ... stopped an object from being rendered, (which doesn't really matter for a non rendered object like a camera, empty etc)

Comment: @batFINGER I tested the code and indeed it says all cameras are "activada". The code doesn't work.

Comment: @MarkusvonBroady You should try pressing the disable in processing icon that is to the right of the name, with that it will tell you camera disabled

Comment: @MrMelqui "disable" an active camera this way and press F12 - the image will still be rendered from that camera. At least in 2.93...