# Hiding specific objects from rendering in one camera while showing on others

Tags: 3d-view, camera

How can I dynamically hide an object from one camera view while allowing it to show on another camera view?

Comment: You can't, use separate scenes

Comment: Ok, I figured using a similar method using Outliner, by simply adding key frames to the render icon's switches.

Comment: This is possible using Drivers - see https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/90723/29586

Comment: Duarte Farrajota Ramos, that method is both counter-intuitive and cumbersome.

Comment: The Driver Method works great. thanks Rich Sedman.

Comment: Can this process be reversed, to instead turn on instead of off.