# Rendering objects only for left or right camera in 2.8

Tags: rendering, render-layers, stereoscopy

I am working on a stereoscopic animation in 2.8 where some objects in the scene should be visible only for the left eye and others only for the right eye.
I use multi-view stereoscopy in cycles. I want to render everything at once as side-by-side stereo images.

(of course I could render them separately by putting them into separate collections, turning them visible and render one eye/camera at once and after then the other. But I want to keep it short)

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/52231/rendering-a-stereoscopic-image-in-blender-2-77

Comment: Related : https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/90723/29586 - this would work for multiple *single* cameras (and switcching between them) but I haven’t tested with multi-view (the driver might not update between cameras - you’d have to specifically test that)

Comment: The problem with two scenes solution (Scene_L+Scene_R=Composite_Scene) is that the size I set two component scenes is 960x1080. The composite scene shall be 1920x1080. But when I prerender then the component scenes are rendered the same size as the composite scene....

Answer (score 2):

Managed to solve the problem by creating three collections. 
In left scene is collection "left", and the collection "right" is instanced here but not rendered.
in right scene is  collection "right", and the collection "left" is instanced here but not rendered.
And finally collection called "both" is linked to both scenes.

For linking or instancing a collection from another scene you have to go to "Scenes" view in Outliner, this enables to see collections from other scenes. You can then right click on the collection you want to link or instance here.

[image: Collections]

Comment: I don't understand how the solution utilizes two different cameras. How do you get camera_L to render all BUT the RIGHT collection & the camera_R to exclude the LEFT collection? I can find the "Instance to scene" option but all that does is remove a collection from render, right? Where are you assigning (or excluding) a collection so you can do a single render with stereoscopy & get it done?