# How to make 2D animation object appear/reappear at specific keyframes? (Blender 2.8)

Tags: animation

So I'm trying to make an animation with text appearing at a specific frame, but I don't see a visibility option I can animate.

I managed to somehow make text appear at a specific frame, but I haven't since been able to reproduce it.

To put simply: I want an image/text/grease drawing/anything to appear on frame 20, then disappear on frame 40.

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/90709/make-an-object-invisible-to-a-specific-camera-cycles

Comment: @DuarteFarrajotaRamos I wish people would actually read the question in full, including the title. Maybe one would know that I'm asking for the solution in Blender 2.8, not 2.7. There is no obvious option to enable/disable camera view of an object in 2.8

Answer (score 2):

Blender 2.80 still has the same functionality for animating the visibility of objects. By default the outliner now has a simplified display but the visibility options can easily be shown in the filter options menu.

[image: outliner filter menu]

Also the visibility options are now available in the object properties, where keyframes can easily be created.

[image: object visibility options]

Answer (score 1):

The hack-ey method is to place the object outside of the camera view, and then next frame put it where you want it to be.