# Automating Blender workflow with opening OBJs and rendering them with options

Tags: scripting

I have never done scripting in Blender, so I am looking how to solve this task. I have 1000 OBJ files that I have to import in Blender one by one, and to render each one under the same setting. The workflow is roughly like this:

- import the OBJ
- rotate and scale the object (constant value)
- create a plane at z=0
- put a lamp at a specific location
- render the image
- move the lamp to a second specific location
- render the second image

And this has to be done 1000 times (for each OBJ).

I am proficient with Python if it helps.

Comment: You could start here, [Batch import Wavefront OBJ](http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/5064/batch-import-wavefront-obj/5065#5065).

Comment: You could try using the [Info panel](http://blender.stackexchange.com/a/7880/599) to help find the names of some operators, but
also have a look at the [api docs](http://www.blender.org/documentation/blender_python_api_2_70_release/)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You will get the API calls for free by pulling down the *Info Header* as shown here:

[image]

Just perform the scene setup manually, select all lines <kbd>A</kbd> and copy'n paste the commands into a python file. You  might want to add the snippet from the comment by iKlsR.

```
bpy.ops.view3d.snap_cursor_to_center()
bpy.ops.mesh.primitive_plane_add(radius=1, view_align=False, enter_editmode=False, location=(0, 0, 0), layers=(True, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False))
bpy.ops.transform.resize(value=(6.39051, 6.39051, 6.39051), constraint_axis=(False, False, False), constraint_orientation='GLOBAL', mirror=False, proportional='DISABLED', proportional_edit_falloff='SMOOTH', proportional_size=1)
bpy.ops.object.lamp_add(type='HEMI', view_align=False, location=(0, 0, 0), layers=(True, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False))
bpy.ops.transform.translate(value=(0, 0, 6.98471), constraint_axis=(False, False, True), constraint_orientation='GLOBAL', mirror=False, proportional='DISABLED', proportional_edit_falloff='SMOOTH', proportional_size=1)
bpy.ops.transform.translate(value=(0, -6.91949, 0), constraint_axis=(False, True, False), constraint_orientation='GLOBAL', mirror=False, proportional='DISABLED', proportional_edit_falloff='SMOOTH', proportional_size=1, release_confirm=True)
bpy.ops.transform.rotate(value=-0.645382, axis=(-0.818828, 0.361665, -0.445779), constraint_axis=(False, False, False), constraint_orientation='GLOBAL', mirror=False, proportional='DISABLED', proportional_edit_falloff='SMOOTH', proportional_size=1)
bpy.context.space_data.context = 'RENDER'
```

Comment: Beware of operators! [Python performance with Blender operators](http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/7358/python-performance-with-blender-operators). For 1k objects, consider a low-level approach for optimal performance.