# How do I use the tooltip to create keybinds?

Tags: shortcut, origin

[image]

The specific command I'm trying to set is bpy.ops.object.origin_set() which sets the origin of an object which is bound to default to <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> +<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd> +<kbd>C</kbd>

This doesn't work:
[image]

Comment: What is your actual goal? Creating a shortcut for *Origin to 3D cursor* without getting the menu? Search for `origin` and see how that's done. Your test doesn't work because you have use the `identifier of the desired operator` not the `function()` call.

Comment: Nah I want the menu to pop up. How do I find the identifier?

Comment: Go to *User Preferences > Input* and type `origin`...

Comment: Yeah duh, in this case. What about Pivot center? Viewport shading? Interaction Mode? I'm coming from here: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/7878/how-do-i-find-the-technical-name-for-a-function-so-i-can-assign-a-hotkey-to-it

Comment: See my edit [here](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/7879/31447). Also consider that you can always right-click the relevant button within the UI to change the shortcut and notice that all previously registered shortcuts listed in *User Preferences > Input* as mentioned before...